# Define homology by simplicial Eilenberg Maclane spectra.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory

Let $H\mathbb{Z}$ be the Eilenberg Maclane spectrum by $(H\mathbb{Z})^k=\tilde{\mathbb{Z}}[S^k]$. Here $S^1 = \Delta[1]/\partial \Delta[1]$ is the simplicial circle and $S^k = S^1\wedge \cdots \wedge S^1$ ($k$ times), and $(\tilde{\mathbb{Z}}[S^k])_n=\mathbb{Z}(S^k)_n/\mathbb{Z}*$, where the $*$ is the basepoint.

It is known that (as in [Motivic Homotopy Theory](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-45897-5), 6.4.1, p23)
$$\tilde{H}_n(X) = \pi_n(H\mathbb{Z} \wedge X)$$
where the homotopy is the stable homotopy. The proof may be given by
$$\tilde{H}_n(X) = \tilde{H}_{n+k}(S^k\wedge X) = \pi_{n+k}(\tilde{\mathbb{Z}}[S^k\wedge X])$$
and
$$\pi_{n+k}((H\mathbb{Z}\wedge X)^k) = \pi_{n+k}(\tilde{Z}[S^k]\wedge X)\rightarrow  \pi_{n+k}(\tilde{Z}[S^k\wedge X])$$
with ***the last map being an isomorphism for*** $k \ge n$.

What I do not know is, why the last map which is induced by $\tilde{Z}[S^k]\wedge X\rightarrow \tilde{Z}[S^k\wedge X]$ is a weak equivalence.